# Text in pop-up notification messages is incorrectly encoded (renders with HTML escape characters)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, popup, warning-message

Very minor UI bug - was voting to delete an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53426818/674039) (5 years late, and doesn't add anything new) but could not due to misclick, and saw in UI that an apostrophe character is rendered with html escape characters:

[image: html escaped apostrophe]

The text could be fixed, but such a `Delete` link could probably just be disabled or hidden when it can't actually be used in the first place.

Comment: Very **not** minor UI bug :) It's network-wide on every notification - HTML tags get escaped and added as plain text as well. See Uber Meta: [You "can&#39;t" vote for your own post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377743/786798)

Comment: They could also just not use a contraction...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Or use `’` instead of `'`…

Comment: This is *much* more widespread than just this single popup, so solutions that would avoid it here are not the answer. I see this in popups from the moderator tools, including those which *should* contain links, but don't anymore, because things are getting incorrectly encoded. I assume there's a double-encoding bug somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed, as are any other toast notifications that show that are related to voting.

> vote confirmation
> including html
> renders properly

Comment: I'm still seeing the escaped text ..

Comment: where are you seeing it?

Comment: The same place I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @wim Also with `Ctrl`+`F5`? Can you reproduce this on Stack Overflow or can you reproduce this on Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes, the place which I mentioned in the question was on Stack Overflow. It's reproducible with a hard refresh, with all cookies and cache cleared, with an incognito window, with both Chrome and Firefox..

Comment: On Stack Overflow, I can’t reproduce the bug anymore.

Comment: It appears fixed now. They may have missed a spot the first time around, somehow. Thanks for the haiku.

Comment: I think that the fix put in [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417412/51) got the ones missed for the current post.