# HTML Tags showing in text area

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, popup, warning-message

I tried deleting my question after it got closed and it gave me an error saying that I can't delete it due to people having invested time into it. However, the `<a>` tag is visible inside the text area.

> [image: Screenshot]

Comment: This was supposed to be fixed: [Badly escaped HTML results in plain text instead of markup in toast notifications (e.g. "You can&#39;t vote for your own post".)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377743) apparently not

Comment: See also [Text in pop-up notification messages is incorrectly encoded (renders with HTML escape characters)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417220/10113238) which this is a regression of

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed. Sorry for missing this one earlier.

> more html
> showing when deleting now
> rendering is fixed

Comment: Did you make a *general* fix to the rendering of these messages, or are you fixing each individual message? I ask, because I saw at least one other such message ~12 hours ago when creating a user account annotation. Do we need to be reporting each individual occurrence?

Comment: If you're having to fix each individual message, why hasn't someone gone through and checked every single one? For that matter, why wasn't that check of all such messages done when the rendering was changed (I'd expect that checking that such a change worked for most/all input would be a normal part of making a change to rendering such messages)?

Comment: How did this happen in the first place anyway? I'd personally assume HTML sanitization is abstracted away into a method precisely to avoid this in the first place, but that doesn't make sense if the fix is on the level of individual messages. This reeks of an enormous DRY violation

Comment: As of 3 hours ago, the toast message for a moderator moving comments to chat is still broken, as is the one for user account annotation creation that Makyen mentioned above. Could someone please check **all** of these?

Comment: And have another one: [Raw HTML displayed when ticking "this is not a duplicate"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417430/6296561)

Comment: Toast for mod action confirmations and for account annotation creation are fixed as well.

Comment: There was a general fix affecting the generation of toast messages that was made for security reasons. As a result, rendering html in toast messages is no longer done by default and now has to be set explicitly in code. Due to the priority on the fix and the difficulty in testing each of the literally thousands of places that use this, while we were able to fix most uses, we weren't able to test every single usage before it went live. This has led to the UI regressions on the different toast messages that have been reported. Please continue to let us know about these when you see them.

Comment: Still not fixed! Just got a https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtI0g.png.

Comment: @GSerg it's probably best to create a post for this so that it can be given a status-review tag and added to Jira. Unless Yaakov or another staff member says otherwise, in which case ignore me and listen to them.

Comment: Please create new posts for new occurrences