# Raw HTML displayed when ticking "this is not a duplicate"

Tags: bug, status-completed

[image]

---

As per title - someone suggested my question was a dupe and when I ticked the "no it's not" button I got this popup.

Comment: Again? [HTML Tags showing in text area](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417407) and [Text in pop-up notification messages is incorrectly encoded (renders with HTML escape characters)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417220)

Comment: This is getting outright ridiculous. We have a number of these reports that are status-complete, and the same issue _still_ persists. Might be about time SE reviews their test systems (or gets one, I guess)

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine this one (about duplicate banner) is even [reported about a week ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417248/839601) and tagged status completed

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine They're each being fixed individually - one being fixed doesn't fix them all.

Comment: working on it. This is all my fault, sorry... and yes, we need to fix them individually

Comment: @Catija we figured. It really doesn't help the situation. Notably, _why_ did no one add tests after the initial breakage, or go back and look at the commit(s) that somehow broke all the dialogs separately, and actually double-check everything? Why is it that we need to raise a number of bug reports, [and still somehow end up with _more_ breaks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417407/html-tags-showing-in-text-area#comment904680_417412)? One being fixed doesn't fix them all, but they shouldn't have been possible to break individually to begin with

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine last time I checked their "test system" were we - the users. However ugly it is, they have an option to make even this system work less painfully, by making it possible to [deploy changes to one of (part of) sites in the network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368686/165773)... quite sad to see that they have chosen to ignore this option

Comment: @gnat might be even better to apply the changes *and allow users to opt-in for them*. Then publishing the changes after X amount of time when it seems like the bugs are fixed. Then we don't get disruptive changes applied to everybody. And users would be far less bothered by bugs if they've explicitly said they want to see them.

Answer (score 2):

This one is fixed. Thanks for letting us know.

> oh no. not again.
> hopefully the last time that
> this issue happens

Comment: Why dont you go through and check every single message instead for waiting for bug reports? Im sure there will be more.

Comment: That is what I spent most of my day today doing.

Comment: @YaakovEllis seems there is yet another one missed - notification when a review of a suggested edit cannot go through as the edit was approved in the meantime. Can't report it properly as I am out of the quota for today, and the occurence is rather rare, but it should be pointer enough to find.